# AngularJS - Service not injected properly into factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

firstly here is my factorys code:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('actionsService', ['$http', '$window', '$q', 'jsUtils', 'dataService', 'perspectivesService', function($http, $window, $q, jsUtils, dataService, perspectivesService) {
    'use strict';

    //some functions

    function buildMenuItem(item, targets, callInvoker) {
        if(...) {
        //some code
        } else {
            perspectivesService.removeExtension(item.id);
        }
    } 
    //some more functions
}]);
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: perspectivesService.removeExtension is not a function

I know the problem isn't comming from my perspectivesService, because I'm injecting it the same way into controllers and calling the same function (removeExtension) and it works fine. There obviously is a problem with the dependency injection here, but I can't figure out exactly what. From what I've read there shouldn't be a problem to inject my service into the factory and it's done the same way you would inject it into a controller.. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

There is my perspectivesService code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myModule').service('perspectivesService', perspectivesService);
    perspectivesService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function perspectivesService($http){
        return {
            removeExtension: removeExtension,
            setEditEnabled: setEditEnabled,
            isEditEnabled: isEditEnabled
        };
        function removeExtension(ext){
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'remove',
                params: { removeExt: ext
                }
            }).then(function(resp){
                console.log('Its was successfull');
            });
        }

        function setEditEnabled(edit){
            localStorage.setItem('editMode', edit);
        }

        function isEditEnabled(){
            if(localStorage.getItem("editMode") === 'true'){
                return true;
            }else if(localStorage.getItem("editMode") === 'false') {
                return false;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: You dependency inject is correct, Show code of `perspectivesService` seems problem is there

Comment: I updated my post with the code

Comment: `perspectivesService` is also fine, how are you referencing these files? Are you bundling them? However you are defining `service` correctly for `perspectivesService` instead use factory i.e. `.factory ('perspectivesService',....`

Comment: Problem fixes - the issue was within the rest of my code - I had anonymous functions calling my buildMenuItem, so this was not defined, thus my perspectivesService was not reachable inside. I fixed it now.. Thank you for the responses.